# Getting second last parameter from querystring with PHP

Tags: php, regex, query-string

I have a URL like so:

```
http://example.com/var1/var2
```

What I'd like to is get VAR 1 from the querystring. I've tried using a regex but I'm not really very familiar with them. Is there an easier way?

Comment: So if it was `/var1/var2/var3/var4` you would want `var3` as it is second to last?  What if it is only `/var1`?

Comment: Hi, no there will only ever be two and there will always be two :)

Comment: That's actually not a _querystring_ though it may be turned into one later `echo basename(dirname('http://example.com/var1/var2'));`

Comment: Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```php
<?php
$e = explode("/",parse_url("http://example.com/a/b")["path"])[1];
// $e now is "a"
```